# Want page numbers to increase by 2 instead of 1

Tags: page-numbering, counters

Does anybody know of a way to change the page number counter so that it increases by 2 instead of 1?

I tried writing

```
\newcommand{\anewpage}{\newpage}    
\renewcommand{\newpage}{\anewpage\stepcounter{page}}
```

and then Texmaker exploded.

Context: I am importing the pdf of a scanned book which has two "real-life" pages per one "electronic" page. I'm fixing the logical page numbering using hyperref and exporting to a pdf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: That's probably doable, but what is your [real problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2450/5763)?

Comment: Well, optimally I'd like to be able to switch the page counter to counting by 2's or counting by 1's at will after the document begins.

Comment: And what is your real [X](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2449/5763)?

Comment: Because wouldn't it be grand? Anyway, my real problem is solved. Thanks for the help. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that effect only when using `\newpage`, the code below works

```
\let\anewpage\newpage
\renewcommand{\newpage}{\anewpage\addtocounter{page}{1}}
```

Comment: I'd use `\stepcounter{page}`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, OK. Do you know if there would be any difference?

Comment: It's just a cleared shortcut for `\addtocounter{foo}{1}`. And then there is `\refstepcounter`...

Comment: @Sigur Thank you! First time using the `let` command.

Comment: @dalbrit, welcomed to TeX.SE.